# i want to buy a budget laptop for blender

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, processor, memory, intel

I am new to blender snd I have been using my old laptop but the performance is too bad, so I wanted to change my laptop, so what is the best laptop with better graphics under 90,000 rupees or 1200 us dollars
I have been gone through some basic specifications like intel core i7 ram 6 GB or more graphics more than 4 GB but I can get find a good laptop with these specifications so pls help me find a good laptop
for rendering nicely

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the new AMD Ryzen 4000 mobile CPUs, a few laptops are about to hit the shelves whith exactly the specs you need, and within your price point. For example the Asus TUF Gaming A15 (90NR03L2-M04070).
CPU: Ryzen 7 4800H with 8 Zen2 cores, just what you want for Blender
GPU: Nvidia RTX 2060
SSD: 512GB NVMe
RAM: 8GB as a single SO-DIMM. I recommend upgrading to 16GB with a second 8GB SO-DIMM
And a nice 1080P IPS panel with 144Hz refresh rate.

It is marketed as a gaming laptop with all the questionable design choices that come with it, but the specs make it pretty much ideal for your requirements at that price point.